# Overloading operators for custom types in Python

Tags: python, operator-overloading, overloading

I am trying to emulate something called "prefix tree" in Python.

My class has the `__contains__` method, so I can check if there's given word in this tree:

```
class PrefTree():
    ...
    def __contains__(self, word):
        #some code...
    ...

pt = PrefTree()
...
w = "someword"
if w in pt:
    print("Aye, found it.")
```

But I also would like to have some special `__contains__` method to check membership using a special rule. So I'll need 'another' `in` operator to check membership with this method. What is the best way to implement that?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question.  You can't create new operators.  There is only one `in` operator, and you can overload it to do one thing (per class).  If you have another kind of containement to test, you could use another existing operator, or just give your class a method so people call `obj.specialContains(whatever)`.

Comment: That's true, I can add a method for that, but to my mind it would look much nicer and more pythonic if I could do `if w special_in pt`

Comment: Well, you can't.  You can't define your own operators; you can only define behavior for the existing operators.

Comment: Can I somehow pass additional arguments to the `__contains__` method when using the `in` operator?

Comment: You can have `__contains__` receive a tuple.  E.g. `(a, b, c) in pt` In this case you could have different behaviors based on the type of the object used, or the number of items in a tuple, etc. Not that I advise that kind of tomfoolery.

Comment: @Thurisaz: Not really.  It's a binary operator, so it can only have two arguments.  You could try to get sneaky as kindall suggests by doing different things based on different sorts of values, but that will probably be more confusing than just using a method call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is only one of the `__contains__` implementations supposed to apply for a given `w`? and then, what determines whether the special rule or the standard one applies? (some characteristic of `w`?)

If both are to be always available to users of your class for any `w`, then obviously you need two different methods.

If, however, something about `w` determines which implementation to use, you can define a superclass of `PrefixTree` - `PrefixTreeBase`, say - containing the default implementation of `__contains__`, and then the PrefixTree implementation would look like this:

```
def __contains__(self, w):
    if self._is_special(w):
        return self._special_rule(w)
    return super().__contains__(w)
```

where the `_*special*` methods implement your notions of specialness.